# Is "coin" still used to mean "money"?

Tags: word-usage, australian-english, money

To clarify, I'm *not* talking about money solely in form of metal coins. (As in: *I then proceeded carefully to count out the entire 14 pounds 78 pence in coin* - [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/coin)).

I'm talking about using 'coin' to mean money in general, a usage that Oxford does NOT define.

I was just watching Mad Max ('79). There's a line where Max says to a shop owner:

> You must have spent some coin. <sub>*(at the 59:09 mark)*</sub>

It's worth mentioning that this usage of 'coin' is frequently encountered in period/fantasy works, most notably in Game of Thrones. But, since money was only available in metal back then, the usage is understandable.

Since Mad Max is an Autralian movie from 1979, I was curious whether this usage was prevalent in Australia, and if it still is.

While we're at it, is 'coin' used this way in BrE/AmE? Was it ever?

Comment: I'm in the UK, and I'm pretty sure I've never heard this usage in natural conversation (going back several decades).

Comment: Acceptable or regular usage? I'd argue that many would understand what's meant but not actually use it themselves.

Comment: @Catija: I doubt *any* native speaker could fail to *understand* the term - but my first assumption would be it was a facetious mock-archaic usage, as per Game of Thrones (or Mad Max, where the "degenerate future" language is also "other-worldly, mock-archaic").

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Maybe today, but not back in '79. I got the feeling it was an informal/slang usage.

Comment: Tushar Raj, you have to bear in mind that Mad Max isn't set in contemporary society, so much of the language is effectively "invented" for the sake of artistic effect (to separate the fictional world of the movie from real life).

Comment: What do you mean Oxford doesn't define it that way? It's the second definition on your link? : *Money in the form of coins: large amounts of coin and precious metal* This is the same usage, even if the definition is a bit limiting. It's completely possible that they only have "coins" as monetary units.

Comment: Funny, I never thought of *coin* referring to coins in the literal sense. It's fairly common in US and Canadian slang to *drop [some] serious coin* on something that somewhat older people would *spend [the] big bucks* for, and even older folks *pay a pretty penny*.

Comment: @Catija: See the example sentences. This usage is exclusively to limit the definition, to highlight that the form of maney used was coins; and is often used after the preposition `in`

Comment: @choster: And the plot thickens...

Comment: It's an expression that would still be understood in most of the US.  Whether it is still in currency with the younger crowd is hard to say -- "drop some coin" or "some serious coin" has a nice slangy ring to it.

Comment: Google Books has 15 written instances of [*you got any coin*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22you+got+any+coin%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22you+got+any+coin%22&tbm=bks&start=10), so apparently it's not totally unknown. But relatively speaking, it's not in the same league as [*you got any **money***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22you+got+any+money%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), with an estimated 147,000 results.

Comment: TusharRaj, re @choster's comment, ngrams shows that using coin metaphorically as money in general has fairly recently risen in popularity](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22some%20serious%20coin%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1990,cd_max:1997&lr=lang_en). If the first Mad Max used it this way, that'd be very interesting (it's outside of the current popularity range)

Comment: 'We are coining it in' or 'That company is coining it in'. I have used, heard and seen fairly frequently in the UK.

Comment: @Christopher: That's coin as a verb, in what looks suspiciously like an idiom. I'm talking about the noun. But thanks for the feedback.

Comment: That's why its a comment, but what are they 'coining'? The 'coin'?

Comment: In my opinion "coin" sounds a little bit slang. I have heard it used, but I can't remember exactly how and when.

Comment: @DogLover: Thanks. Would you say it's more common in AusE than BrE/AmE?

Comment: It sounds more British to me to be honest.

Comment: @HotLicks "some serious coin" was definitely US slang in the 1980s.

Answer (score 3):

The Oxford English Dictionary cites

> **[coin](http://findwords.info/term/coin)**
>
> 6. (without pl.) Coined money, esp. that in circulation or current; specie, money.
>      In slang use this has passed into ‘cash, money generally’, as in ‘***I haven't the coin to do it***’.
>
> **1406** Hoccleve Misrule 133 *Lak of coyn departith compaignie*.
>   **1530** Palsgr. 487 *He hath clypped the kynges quoyne*.
>    **1556** Chron. Gr. Friars (1852) 5 *A proclamacion for the new qwyne that no man should speak ill of it*.
>   **1653** Urquhart Rabelais i. xlvi, *Coine is the sineus of warre*.
>   **1735** Berkeley Querist §475 *Wealth is really power, and coin a ticket conveying power*.
>    **1855** Macaulay Hist. Eng. IV. 695 *The manufacturers generally contrived..to pay their workmen in coin*.
>   **1874** Hotten Slang Dict. 124 ‘*To post the coin*’.. a sporting phrase meaning to make a deposit of money for a match of any kind.
>   **1904** G. V. Hobart Jim Hickey ii. 35 *Wouldn't we be a nice pair of turtles to stand around with coin in our jeans and see a nice girl..getting the ice?*
>   **1926** J. Black You can't Win vii. 82 *I'll get the coin on that junk in an hour*. Ibid. ix. 104 *You put me in the hole for some coin.* -

Wikipedia has a page on slang terms for money

> **[United Kingdom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slang_terms_for_money#United_Kingdom)**
>
> Other general terms for money include "bread" (cockney rhyming slang 'bread & honey', money. This also became dough, by derivation from the same root), "cabbage", "clam", "milk", "dosh", "dough", "shillings", "frogskins", "notes", "duckets", "loot", "bones", "**coin**", "folding stuff", "honk", "lolly", "lucre"/"filthy "Lucre", "moola/moolah", "paper", "scratch", "readies", "spondulicks/spondoolic(k)s/spondulix/spondoolies", and "wonga".

Since the 19th century the term *coin* is slang for money in the US

> [coin](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/coin)
>   Money; bread, loot (1870s+)
>   <sup>*The Dictionary of American Slang*</sup>

The American English (red line) and British English (blue line) corpuses on Google Ngram show that the uncountable noun *coin* (*[much coin](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=much%20coin%3Aeng_gb_2009%2C%20much%20coin%3Aeng_us_2009&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmuch%20coin%3Aeng_gb_2009%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmuch%20coin%3Aeng_us_2009%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmuch%20coin%3Aeng_gb_2009%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cmuch%20coin%3Aeng_us_2009%3B%2Cc1)*) is in steady decline since the early 20th century, and is becoming obsolete in the UK.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. This was very informative and comprehensive. Have you encountered this usage personally?

Comment: Can't say I have. Wish, I could :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, and I know I'll never get an answer. Because I never do. What's the downvote for? For given four trustworthy references? For not answering the OP? I'm baffled.

Comment: The answer is "just because", as always. I took this to meta. [Take a look](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6873/the-first-anonymous-downvote)

Comment: I kinda knew that, going in. But now, I can at least tell myself that I tried. Even if my proposal is deemed flawed, this is a serious problem and a solution is long overdue.

Comment: I see this post got an upvote. So it would no longer be in the unanswered queue. I can add my upvote now.

Answer (score -1):

If someone in literature uses coin for money I would say it is a tradtional figure of speech with the artistic effect of a different way of expression.
I would say "coin" for "money" is a synecdoche (Greek term) or pars pro toto (Latin term). The Latin term means using a word that denotes only part of a whole. And coins are only part of the term money.
A typical pars pro toto is "crown" for the King.

Answer (score -1):

The use of "coin" to mean money, is actually a figure of speech called [metonymy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy). In this figure of speech an example or a related word, in this case coin, which is a type of money, is used to represent the original concept -- money. This usage is similar to the use of the word "press", which is an instrument for printing newspapers, to represent the newspaper produced by it (and also by a second metonymy, the people who produce those newspapers.)

The use of "coin" in this fashion has a very old fashioned sound to it though, perhaps due to the decline in the use of the actual metal tokens. However, it would be widely understood.